# how do you place an admob ad with html 5 on your app

Tags: javascript, html, admob, intel-xdk

I am building an app with html 5 want to place a banner ad at the bottom of the screen. I have the ad code but do not know how to place it with html5.
thanks this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code that will just add an AdMob banner at the bottom, it can be opened in Intel XDK, it used AdMob Cordova plugin.

https://github.com/krisrak/html5-cordova-plugin-admob